# Can you exclude classes with packagingOptions in android gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to exclude class files or use pickfirst for classes in a jar file dependency.  We always seem to run into issues where third party libs package up jars in aar files instead of using gradle dependencies and therefore cause duplicate file zip exceptions:

like this:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/StringEncoderComparator.class
```

The only solution we've found so far is to unzip the aar, delete the offending jar, and rezip it back up.  Is there a way to just exclude the jar or class from gradle?

Looking at the source it seems like I should be able to use packaging options. So I've tried various combinations of pick first and exclude but no luck:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst '**/StringEncoderComparator.class'
    pickFirst 'org/apache/commons/codec/StringEncoderComparator.class'
    pickFirst 'org/apache/commons/codec/*'

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am also stuck on this, any news?

Comment: Nope, never did find a way.

Comment: How to exclude java files?

Answer (score 0):

Use resolutionStrategy.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

```
apply plugin: 'java' //so that there are some configurations

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    // fail eagerly on version conflict (includes transitive dependencies)
    // e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal)
    failOnVersionConflict()

    // prefer modules that are part of this build (multi-project or composite build) over external modules
    preferProjectModules()

    // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
    //  *append new forced modules:
    force 'asm:asm-all:3.3.1', 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
    //  *replace existing forced modules with new ones:
    forcedModules = ['asm:asm-all:3.3.1']

    // add dependency substitution rules
    dependencySubstitution {
      substitute module('org.gradle:api') with project(':api')
      substitute project(':util') with module('org.gradle:util:3.0')
    }

    // cache dynamic versions for 10 minutes
    cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10*60, 'seconds'
    // don't cache changing modules at all
    cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
  }
}
```